# Communicating with fragment when it becomes the top of the backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have two Fragments: `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`. I start `FragmentA` from my `ActivityMain`, then I start `FragmentB` without popping `FragmentA` from the backstack (I want to display `FragmentA` in the background of `FragmentB`). Eventually I am done with `FragmentB` and pop it from the backstack but I need to inform Fragment A that `FragmentB` is no longer in use.

How do I communicate to `FragmentA` that `FragmentB` was closed and that `FragmentA` is now the top of the backstack?

I've tried putting breakpoints in many of Fragment's classes such as OnResume(),OnAttach, OnStart() but nothing gets hit.

Comment: See this link:https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/onactivityresult-in-fragment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [setTargetFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int)) method.

> Optional target for this fragment. This may be used, for example, if
>   this fragment is being started by another, and when done wants to give
>   a result back to the first. The target set here is retained across
>   instances via.

Back to your case, when start `FragmentB` from `FragmentA`.

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        val REQUEST_CODE_FRAGMENT_A = 1
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)!!

        val fragmentB = FragmentB().apply {
            setTargetFragment(this@FragmentA, REQUEST_CODE_FRAGMENT_A)
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragmentB, "fragB")
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FRAGMENT_A) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val message = data?.getStringExtra("message")
                Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When `FragmentB` popped from the backstack, `onDestroy` method will be called.

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {

    override fun onDestroy() {
        // Notify for FragmentA (as target fragment) that FragmentB destroyed.
        val intent = Intent().apply { putExtra("message", "I'm out.") }
        targetFragment.onActivityResult(targetRequestCode, Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```